# How can I make my Python Discord bot check if a message was sent by the bot itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am writing a Discord bot using Python (v. 3.6.1) which detects all messages sent in a channel and replies to them in that same channel. However, the bot replies to messages by itself, causing an infinite loop.

````
@bot.event
async def on_message(message)
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, message.content)```
````

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`message`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message) class contains information on the message's [`author`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author), which you can utilize to determine whether or not to respond to the message. `author` is a [`Member`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) object (or its superclass [`User`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User) if the channel is private), which has an `id` property but also supports direct logical comparisons between users.

For example:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != bot.user:
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, message.content)
```

Should function as desired

Comment: the variable bot.user no longer exists, can someone pls tell me the new version of this

Comment: `bot.user` now points to the person that creates the bot, so this no longer works

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is from years ago but incase anybody else is googling this question like me, the message object that is passed to on_message has an author object inside of it, which has an attribute named "bot" which is true or false (true if it is a bot). So you can configure your function to safely ignore any messages by other bots by including this if statement at the beginning:

```
def on_message(self, message):
    if (message.author.bot):
        return #if this is true: then it is by a bot.
```