# How do I get a bot to forward its DMs

Tags: discord.py

So my bot DM's users and asks them questions, but I need to be able to see their response in a channel.

So far I have this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(642759168247463937)
    await channel.send('message')
```

but it begins when any message is sent in any channel and it also responds to itself, causing an endless loop of spam.

I'm new to Discord.py so I honestly don't have a clue on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Use [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) to wait for messages inside a coroutine.

Comment: Regarding the spam. The on_message event signifies that the code written inside the function is executed when the bot receives a message, this includes when the bot receives a message from itself which causes it to reply to itself indefinitely. To prevent the endless stream of spam you can add a check at the start, see [How can make my Python Discord bot I check if a message was sent by the bot itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47908539/11624866) for details.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to check if the message came from DMs:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.guild:
        return
    channel = bot.get_channel(642759168247463937)
    await channel.send('message')
```

This works because `message.guild` is `None` if the message was sent in DMs. This prevents the spam problem, since the message is not forwarded to the bot's DMs.
However, to avoid the spam in general, it is good practice to avoid responding to bots altogether, unless necessary. Luckily, `User` and `Member` objects have an attribute called `bot` that helps us here:

```py
if message.author.bot:
    return
```

Note that this is done automatically for commands using the `ext.commands` framework.